# How to use prepared statements in Sqflite for Flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite

How do I use prepared statements in Sqflite in Flutter?
It seems to be missing some functions or it's just completely differently arranged.
Currently, I'm using the standard rawInsert but my strings can sometimes break the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the question mark syntax.

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM t WHERE c = ?", [myString]);
```

Comment: And how does it cause the statement to be prepared and reused in the future?

Comment: @Andrew It doesn't get prepared and reused as far as I know. If you want low level control you can take a look at: https://pub.dev/packages/sqlite3
Although, from experience with a heavily based Sqlite app on Flutter, you don't really need to care that much about PreparedStatements. Performance has always been great (50K+ rows tables and multiple joins)

Answer (score 0):

I am using transaction with rawInsert. In this code inserting will be ignored if there is an existing record.

```
return await Storage.database.transaction((txn) async {
      await txn.rawInsert('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO $tableName(id, sender_id, recipient_id, message_id, message)' + 'VALUES("$id", "$senderId", "$recipientId", "$messageId", "$message")');
}).catchError((e) {
      throw (e);
});
```